# How to use the same vscode shell for sourcing enviroment first and launching the gdb

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-debugger, vscode-tasks

I am trying to launch a specific gdb debugger that will need first to source the needed environment script. I don't want to create one script that does the environment sourcing and execute the gdb debugger.

How can I do that?

I managed to create a launch configuration entry, see:

launch.json file:

```
{
  "name": "debug active file",
  "type": "cppdbg",
  "request": "launch",
  "program": "/indir/binary/indir_do",
  "args": [],
  "stopAtEntry": false,
  "cwd": "/indir/binary/",
  "environment": [],
  "externalConsole": false,
  "MIMode": "gdb",
  "setupCommands": [
    {
      "description": "Enable pretty-printing for gdb",
      "text": "-enable-pretty-printing",
      "ignoreFailures": true
    },
    {
      "description": "Set Disassembly Flavor to Intel",
      "text": "-gdb-set disassembly-flavor intel",
      "ignoreFailures": true
    }
  ],
  "preLaunchTask": "sourceEnv",
  "miDebuggerPath": "/usr/bin/ntox86_64-gdb"
},
```

tasks.json file:

```
{
  "type": "shell",
  "label": "sourceEnv",
  
  "command": "source",
  "args": [
    "$ROOT_DIR/tools/env.sh"
  ],
  "group": "build"
},
```

Although I see that the task is executed in a vscode shell the debug is launched in a different vscode shell and it fails because the environment is not sourced.

How can I make the launch configuration to use the already existing vscode shell?

Comment: Why not use the `environment` field or the `envFile` field? Does your script do anything complicated? Or does it just define variables without any control flow?

Comment: run the environment script in a terminal before launching VSC from the SAME terminal